# How to apply event.stopPropagation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Let me explain the problem first. I am using the following UL structure:

```
<ul onmouseover="smenu_over(this)" onmouseout="smenu_out(this)" class="sub-menu" style="left:0;">
            <li><a href="#">Navigation Item with long text do text wrap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub nav item</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom:0;"><a href="#">Sub nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
```

JS Function

```
function smenu_over(obj) {
  var a = obj.parentNode.childNodes[0];
  if(a!=null) {
   var top = $(".topnav_icons").length && !$(".logo_t").length ? "-45px" : "-34px"; 
   setBckPosition(a, top);
   a.style.color = "#fff";
  }
 }
```

I need to apply the `event.stopPropagation` inside this function which is called when `mouseover` event happen.

Please help me the code to apply `event.stopPropagation`?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
$('ul.sub-menu a').mouseenter(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();

   // your code....
});
```

Comment: let me try your code... actually i am getting an issue with IE. so need to apply the stopPropagation.

Let me try your code.

Comment: your code is not working because i need to pass the current index (this) to the function to get the current ul where mouseover/mouseout event occur.

Please suggest on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your current handlers from being in-line, like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="left:0;">
```

Then you can bind these functions in jQuery, like this:

```
$(function() { //run when DOM is ready
  $("ul.sub-menu").hover(smenu_over, smenu_out);
});
```

In your functions, instead of `obj` just use `this`, it'll refer to the element you're hovering, like this:

```
function smenu_over() {
  var a = this.parentNode.childNodes[0];
  if(a!=null) {
    var top = $(".topnav_icons").length && !$(".logo_t").length ? "-45px" : "-34px"; 
    setBckPosition(a, top);
    a.style.color = "#fff";
  }
}
```

The important difference here is [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) maps to the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events (*not* [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)/[`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)), which *don't* fire on the parent when entering/leaving a child, so no need to stop propagation, they already behave like you want.

You can probably optimize this much further, but without seeing your other code I don't want to give you any bad advice, this will fix the current issue though.